# How to get the hidden value for the input stored in php

Tags: php, variables, input

I wrote php file `p1` that created a form to store values into fields by using `<?php>` tag, while I was trying to use file `delete_product.php` to get the input, why when I echo the variable, nothing showed up?

**p1:**

```
require('database.php');
$query = 'select * from products';
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_result($productCode, $name, $version, $releaseDate);
$stmt->execute();


<table border="1px solid black" border-collapse="collapse">';
echo'<tr><th>Code</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Version</th> <th>Release Date</th> <th> </th></tr>';

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo"<tr> <td>$productCode</td> <td>$name</td> <td>$version</td> <td>$releaseDate</td>
          <td><form action=\"delete_product.php\" method=\"post\">
          <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$productCode\" name=\"code\">
          <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Delete\">
          </form></td></tr>";
```

**delete_product.php:**

```
<?php

$product_code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "code");

echo $product_code;
?>
```

Comment: `<table border="1px solid black" border-collapse="collapse">';` Is it correct?

Comment: If you view the page source of p1.php in a browser, does it have a value populated? It could be that it is posting ""

Comment: yes, p1 works fine, it can correctly show the table with query data.

Answer (score 0):

Please check input field hidden contain the value or not using firebug. if this show null then please check in your record. if it contain value then press the delete button.

Comment: it does contain the value inside the hidden input field.

Comment: it does contain the value inside the hidden input field. when I inspect the code, it shows something like this: '<main>
    <h2>Product List</h2>
<table border="1px solid black" border-collapse="collapse"><tr><th>Code</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Version</th> <th>Release Date</th> <th> </th></tr><tr> <td>DRAFT10</td> <td>Draft Manager 1.0</td> <td>1.0</td> <td>2012-03-01 00:00:00</td>
          <td><form action="delete_product.php" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" value="DRAFT10" name="code">
          <input type="submit" value="Delete">
          </form></td></tr>'

Comment: but when I press delete button, nothing showed in "echo $productCode" in page.